# How to calculate execution time (php directive 'max_execution_time'? )

Tags: php, bash, shell

A few days ago wrote a php script that goes through all my music and reads id3 tags for each song and inserts those in a mysql database.  Here's a snippet for context:

```
exec ( "find /songs -type f -iname '*mp3'", $song_path );
$number_of_songs = count($song_path);
for($i=0; $i<$number_of_songs; $i++){
    //read id3 tags
    //store id3 tags into database
}
```

I changed the php directive `max_execution_time` in apache2/php.ini to gain a better understanding of what this directive does.

When I set `max_execution_time = 10`, my php script runs for about 45 seconds and successfully reads the id3 tags for about 150 songs (Out of thousands of songs) and inserts those tags into a mysql database before terminating the script and outputting the following to the screen:

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in /websites/.../public_html/GetID3()/getid3/module.audio.mp3.php on line 1894**

From the documentation, *'The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc'*  http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

1. What can I infer from the difference between the
   `maximum_execution_time` being set at 10 seconds and the script
   running for a total of 45 seconds before terminating?  Does this
   mean out of the 45 seconds, 35 were spent doing non-php related
   activities like reading the id3 tags, inserting data into mysql etc..., while 10 were spent
   doing php related activities like iterating the loop?
2. Is there a way I can calculate the execution time and print it to
       the screen?

**EDIT**
Using the timer Dagon suggested, I called the getTime() function at the end of the loop, there were about 100+ iterations of the loop.  Here is the output to my browser:

0.1163 seconds

0.8142 seconds

1.1379 seconds

1.5555 seconds

...

76.7847 seconds

77.2008 seconds

77.6071 seconds

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in /websites/.../public_html/GetID3()/getid3/module.audio.mp3.php on line 505

Comment: Do you happen to be using set_time_limit (http://php.net/set_time_limit)? 'When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.'

Comment: No I'm not using set_time_limit

Answer (score 3):

```
<!-- Paste this at the top of the page -->
<?php
   $mic_time = microtime();
   $mic_time = explode(" ",$mic_time);
   $mic_time = $mic_time[1] + $mic_time[0];
   $start_time = $mic_time;
?>

<!-- Write Your script(executable code) here  -->

enter code here

<!-- Paste  this code at the bottom of the page -->
<?php
   $mic_time = microtime();
   $mic_time = explode(" ",$mic_time);
   $mic_time = $mic_time[1] + $mic_time[0];
   $endtime = $mic_time;
   $total_execution_time = ($endtime - $start_time);
   echo "Total Executaion Time ".$total_execution_time." seconds";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't believe the script is actully running for more than 10 seconds, you need to put a proper timer in it

```
<!-- put this at the top of the page -->
<?php
function getTime() {
    $timer = explode( ' ', microtime() );
    $timer = $timer[1] + $timer[0];
    return $timer;
}

$start = getTime();
?> 

<!-- put other code and html in here --> 

<!-- put this code at the bottom of the page -->
<?php
$end = getTime();
$time_took=  round($end - $start,4).' seconds';
echo $time_took;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of script should really be executed in the CLI environment, not in a php process executed by your web server. As per the [manual docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php) on how the PHP command line environment differs from other PHP SAPIs:

> PHP in a shell environment tends to be used for a much more diverse
>   range of purposes than typical Web-based scripts, and as these can be
>   very long-running, **the maximum execution time is set to unlimited**.

While it doesn't answer your question, it does solve your problem :)

Comment: Hey rd, thanks man.  I process scripts via cli, however in this case I want to make a website where users can log in/out so that I can parse their id3 tags which is why I'm testing it from the cgi.

Comment: btw you resemble adam levine: the singer of maroon 5

Comment: @LedZeppelin haha when I lived in LA I used to go along with it late at night when drunk girls said the same thing. As for your website use case ... you might be better served to spawn a new process to handle the tag parsing. That way you could still take advantage of the "CLI" environment. Also, for this type of processing job you should consider using some sort of queue system because long processing jobs like that aren't well suited for a single web server php process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if I ever finish this project, I'll move to amazon ec2 and get some high-cpu reserved instances but for now I'm just getting hands on with the server in my room.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you not only try to measure the script duration, but also try to limit it. And in your case `max_execution_time` is not what you want.

Basically, *"The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc"* is correct. If you need to limit real-time script length, you need to implement your own time measurement. People usually write some benchmark class for it, which after all will be helpful in optimizing the script, but simple

```
$timer['start'] = time();
$timer['max_exec_time'] = 10; // seconds
```

at start and

```
if (time() > $timer['start'] + $timer['max_exec_time'])
    break; // or exit; etc
```

at the end of the loop or anywhere else you want should be enough.